# 'function' object has no attribute even after importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
deviations = returns - returns.mean() squared_deviations =
deviations**2 variance = squared_deviations.mean() 
import numpy as np
volatility = np.sqrt(variance) volatility
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
'function' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

I am confused as I have written this text before and it seems to have worked fine. I even do simple stuff like `returns.std()` and I get the same response.

```
'function' object has no attribute even after importing pandas
```

I have already imported NumPy and pandas

Comment: you assigned to `returns` some function then, what's `print(returns)`

Comment: show us the code for 'returns'